# Using SATA drives with SAS shared backplane?

Tags: storage, sata, sas

Is it possible to use SATA drives when you have a SAS shared backplane to be able to address the drives?

Comment: What type of server, hardware, controller and/or JBOD enclosure are you using?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. It's definitely not ideal, but yes, you can.

Scenarios...

- Shared backplane behind a SAS expander. **Not good.**
- Shared backplane with dedicated 4-lane SAS connectors (e.g. a Dell or HP server's internal drive bays with 1:1 port controller port to disk bay mapping). **Okay.**

I tell people to just [use nearline SAS instead of SATA](https://serverfault.com/questions/331499/how-can-a-single-disk-in-a-hardware-sata-raid-10-array-bring-the-entire-array-to/331504#331504) these days, just to avoid any issues. Expanders tend to cause more problems in these mixed scenarios.

[Technical explanation in detail.](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/840#issuecomment-7134386)

*It's when you add SAS expanders (and SATA Tunneling Protocol) to the mix that you start encountering weird errors with misbehaving SATA disks. SATA simply isn't designed with a switching fabric in mind, and it looks like firmwares still aren't robust enough to deal with command tunneling reliably in the presence of errors.*

Answer (score 3):

SIMPLE answer: yes.

COMPLEX answer: Yes, IF the SATA drives actually behave correctly - some do not. Too few checks, so you get issues.

I run a 24 slow SA backplane full with SATA drives (SSD, Velociraptors) and I DID have a share of Problems under load. SSD Firmwareupdates got them under control.

http://www.adaptec.com/blog/?p=1951

isa blog post about a similar experience ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's depend of SAS architecture. If your backplane have connector type SFF 8482 it is compatible.
See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_attached_SCSI#Architecture