# IOPS bottleneck in design?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iops, storage-spaces

I'm building a 45 drives (backblaze) storage pod for use with Windows 2012 R2 Storage spaces.  Spec is 2xE5-2620 v2 cpus, 32 GB ram, 3xLSI 9201-16i cards, 9x1 TB SATA  SSDs, and 36x4TB HGST ultrastar SATA drives.  Assuming a 50/50 read/write, the raw numbers from the drives clocks in at 840,000 IOPS.  The LSI cards can handle 400k+ iops per card.  Assuming I put the drives in a 3 way mirror I'll have 48 TB of magnetic storage, using the SSD's as tiered storage.  What would be the bottleneck on such a system?  Would it be RAM or cpu or LSI card or the drives themselves?  Would we see anything close to 50% of that theoretical max in iops?

Comment: I'm looking for someone who has real world experience in these types of things to point out if I've overlooked something obvious.  More ram, bigger cpus, etc.

Comment: I understand what you're looking for. All of this is **completely** dependent on **your specific** usage and load profile, which is made clear in the linked duplicate question.

Comment: @chris.w.mclean What size and type (random/sequential matters a lot for the spinning discs) of IOPS are you looking at?  That number seems extremely high.  What's the reason for the 3-way mirror?  (That will cut your write IOPS to a third of theoretical off the top)

Comment: Geez, I'd be doing this in [ZFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS). But really, those Backblaze pods are low-quality. I hope this isn't going to run anything critical.

Comment: The system will be holding a few vms, the workload will be messages dropped into msmq, then passed around to other queues for massaging/correction before being eventually pushed into a sql 2014 db.  Messages are between 4k-10MB in size, (average probably around 6k).  So I think we will be seeing something close to 50/50 r/w on the disk access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on what you'll be doing with the system. And this is generic advice; the same for a Windows Storage Spaces solution, versus ZFS, versus traditional filesystems.

Think about it like this:

- You're using a bunch of capacity-optimized disks, so whatever you're doing seems like it involves a large amount of data.
- When people talk about large datasets, the application is usually backup or something where the active *working set* of data is just a subset of the data on disk.
- If the purpose is backups, why do the specific IOPS matter?
- If the purpose is some other application with a relatively small working set, I'm assuming it can be handled at the SSD caching layer.
- If random read/write performance is important, this is the wrong solution.
- **How will you get data onto and off of the server? If anything, *that* would be your try bottleneck.**
- Advanced filesystems luckily don't need much CPU horsepower. Your CPU is what I normally spec in ZFS storage systems. You may want more RAM, but I don't know the specifics of how WSS leverages physical memory.

In reality, your issues will probably be [SATA disk timeouts](https://serverfault.com/questions/331499/how-can-a-single-disk-in-a-hardware-sata-raid-10-array-bring-the-entire-array-to/331504#331504), failed drives, controller issues (firmware), power and cooling, vibration... And *bugs*. We rarely hear about Windows Storage Spaces here, so my guess is that the industry mindshare is low.

Why can I say this? I've had to administer Backblaze units and [personally own a Sun x4540](https://flic.kr/s/aHsjcwdHBQ) full of *SATA* disks (**meh**). Even with all of those disks, this setup really is only going to be suitable for sequential and streaming workloads.

Comment: Thanks ewwhite!  I think this lets me know that this isn't going to be a solution for what we're planning.  Back to the drawing board!

Comment: +1 for pointing out the network side. The IO Looks monstrous - but this is a file server. THis is enough IO bandwidth to serve possible multiple 10g connections at the same time (which then hits a memory bandwidth limit).